# Cant display lastname facebook js sdk?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I am trying to display last name of the user in a form, using Javascript SDK but its not working.

HTML:

```
  <tr>
    <td align="center">Post as:</td>
    <td align="center"><div id='lastname'></div></td>
  </tr>
```

JS:

```
<script>
  FB.init({
    appId      : '411404219053578',
    status     : true,
    xfbml      : true,
    version    : 'v2.4' // or v2.0, v2.1, v2.0
  });



FB.api('/me', {fields: 'last_name'}, function(response) {
document.getElementById('lastname').innerHTML = response;
});
</script>
```

Am I doing something wrong? And also what should I use for displaying first name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the response is an Object and not a String. So the moment you assign it as the innerHTML, it won't work as you expect.
To solve the problem in your code, you should specify you want to use the last_name like this "response.last_name" or the entire block:

```
FB.api('/me', {fields: 'last_name'}, function(response) {
  document.getElementById('lastname').innerHTML = response.last_name;
});
```

To also get the name, or what I assume you mean the first name, you have two options:

1) In your request, add *first_name* as one of the fields. You do so by changing this *{fields: 'last_name'}* to this **{fields: 'last_name,first_name'}**. The idea is that you can request any field that the facebook API offers, by separating each with a comma. The full block in your case could go something like this:

```
FB.api('/me', {fields: 'last_name,first_name'}, function(response) {
  document.getElementById('lastname').innerHTML = response.first_name + response.last_name;
});
```

2) But if all you want is to display the full name, you can omit passing the fields object and what you will get back is the full name. It would look something like this:

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  document.getElementById('lastname').innerHTML = response.name;
});
```